# FIDO2 passkey attestaionobject fmt value 'none' wh

Tags: javascript, passkey

'FIDO2 passkey attestaionobject fmt value none'? Tested with a different cell phone, it's 'None'.

The fmt value is generated in other ways, but the fmt value is 'none' on the cell phone.

please help me... I don't know why.

Any small hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most synced passkeys are not attested today, which is why the format is "none".